# Is a thread always running on the same core?

Tags: multithreading

Is a thread, once it is started, always running on the same CPU until it terminates? Or is it OS/Implementation dependent?

I'm asking this out of curiousity.

Comment: If there is only single CPU core, yes. For multicore machine answer is "usually no" (thread migration between cores is possible), but is OS/implementation depended. There is "setaffinity" calls in some OS/libs/pthreads to bind some threads to the some subset of available CPU cores.

Comment: Short answer: no, threads will hop cores as the scheduler sees fit. If you are curious about the details (at least for Windows) you might want to take a look at [Windows Internals 6th Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735648735) (ISBN: 978-0735648739). Half of Chapter 5 is devoted to explaining thread scheduling in depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, on a multi-core box, no.  If the same core can be used, there may be an advantage to be gained by making use of data still in the L1 cache, as posted by others, but the downside of expicitly forcing core affinity is bad:

Thread X is created and bound to core 0.
Thread X runs.
Thread X blocks on a system call, for I/O or inter-thread comms maybe.
The OS runs thread Y on core 0.
Thread X becomes ready while cores 1, 2 and 3 are idle.

Now what?

Preempt thread Y unnecessarily?  Overhead of moving Y, plus what if Y is also bound to core 0?
Block X again until Y blocks?  Prevents X making progress when it could do.

Answer (score 2):

It's OS dependent, 
however in general OS's try to make threads run on the same cores because data the thread has used has a higher chance of still being cached in that core, thus increasing performance.

It's all based on the thread sheduling mechanics.